# CloudWatch Logs group cannot be created when an error occurs in SSM send-command

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-ssm, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I executed `aws ssm send-command`. I want ssm to export log to CloudWatch Logs.
Though I executed below clearly error command, it cannot be exported.

```
aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --document-version "1" --targets '[{"Key":"InstanceIds","Values":["my instance"]}]' --parameters '{"commands":["sh ./testing_app_run.s"],"executionTimeout":["3600"]}' --timeout-seconds 600 --max-concurrency "50" --max-errors "0" --cloud-watch-output-config '{"CloudWatchOutputEnabled":true}' --region ap-northeast-1
```

I confirmed the error and the error logs in AWS System Manager of Management Console.
Error messages about logging is not found.

CloudWatch Logs group want be created and send-command log want be exported in it.